# Trying to pass props in React using React Router - saying the value is null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-props

I am trying to pass props in order to use the React Router as part of a project I am in. I keep getting the error from this code that links is null, and I am not sure why -

Header component:
[![header][1]][1]

```
export default function Nav({ links }) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          {links.map((link, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{link}</li>
        ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Navigation Component:

```
[![nav][2]][2]

// Bringing in the required import from 'react-router-dom'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './Header';

export default function Nav() {
  // The Navbar UI component will render each of the Link elements in the links prop
  return (
    <Header
      links={[
        <Link key={1} className="nav-link text-light" to="/about">
          Home
        </Link>,
        <Link key={2} className="nav-link text-light" to="/contact">
          About Us
        </Link>,
        <Link key={3} className="nav-link text-light" to="/portfolio">
        Portfolio
      </Link>,
      <Link key={4} className="nav-link text-light" to="/resume">
      Portfolio
    </Link>,
      ]}
    />
  );
}
```

Error message I am receiving:

```
[![error][3]][3]

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at Nav (http://127.0.0.1:3000/src/components/Header.jsx?t=1701476841986:18:379)
    at renderWithHooks (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:12169:26)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:14919:21)
    at beginWork (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:15900:22)
    at beginWork$1 (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:19747:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:19192:20)
    at workLoopSync (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:19131:13)
    at renderRootSync (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:19110:15)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:18730:28)
    at performConcurrentWorkOnRoot (http://127.0.0.1:3000/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-MMW4JUSU.js?v=39b7b9ed:18678:30)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

I have used ChatGPT extensively and cannot figure out this issue

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwZRi.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeJVh.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8TlNg.png
```

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include actual code snippets instead of images of code. See [mcve]. Include the error message as plain text as well, and if there are any accompanying error stacktraces, please include them.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not be passing the JSX as array values in a property the way you are.  Recognize that JSX is really just a short-hand to calling functions (components) while providing context for the parents and children around those components. The way you have the `links` parameter, it is passing elements that are the result of nested function calls not in a place where React is expecting those functions (components) to be called.

The way I'd approach this would be:

```js
<Header
  links={[
    {className: "nav-link text-light", to: "/about", label: "Home"},
    {className: "nav-link text-light", to: "/contact", label: "About Us"},
    {className: "nav-link text-light" to: "/portfolio", label: "Portfolio"},
    {className: "nav-link text-light", to: "/resume", label: "Resume"}
  ]}
/>
```

and then:

```js
export default function Nav({ links }) {
  return (
    <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-secondary">
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
            {links.map((link, index) => (
              <li key={index}>
                <Link className={link.className} to={link.to}>
                  {link.label}
                </Link>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

Comment: Passing JSX values as props is perfectly valid, there's not any issue doing so in React. The issue OP has is that the `links` prop is undefined in their code when trying to call a `map` function/property on it. This answer doesn't really address the issue OP is asking about.

Comment: I didn't say it isn't valid.  I said that I personally wouldn't.  I have spent way too much time cleaning up invalid uses of JSX.  IMO, JSX should only be used in a `return()` [with minor exceptions that aren't worth talking about here].  I don't understand how `links` is undefined based on the code presented above?  [Though the fact that the first code block is `export default function Nav(......)` is also confusing].

Comment: You kind of implied it. I was disagreeing with the explanation of your opinion, e.g. the "The way you have the links parameter, it is passing elements that are the result of nested function calls not in a place where React is expecting those functions (components) to be called." bit. React doesn't care really what you pass as props, so long as what you ultimately render to the DOM is valid JSX. Passing JSX values in props is perfectly valid as far as React cares. I don't know why OP's original code wasn't working either, but I suspect we had a quite incomplete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out cause of issue, rewrote from scratch, it worked.

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./styles.css";
const Header = ({ links }) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          {links.map((link, index) => (
            <li key={index}>{link}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  const headerLinks = [
    <Link key={1} className="nav-link text-light" to="/home">
      Home
    </Link>,
    <Link key={2} className="nav-link text-light" to="/about-us">
      About Us
    </Link>,
    <Link key={3} className="nav-link text-light" to="/portfolio">
      Portfolio
    </Link>,
    <Link key={4} className="nav-link text-light" to="/resume">
      Resume
    </Link>,
  ];

  return (
    <Router>
      <Header links={headerLinks} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

styles.css

```
header {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.nav-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ffd700;
}
```

If you wanna play around with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/nervous-jennings-h7rwpn?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A5%2C32)

Use preview link of codesanbox on your browser to view routing.